# How do I extract data out from an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am coding in C#. I have this code that tells me the difference in my 2 listview's data.

```
var diff = ListViewDatabase.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                           .Select(x => x.SubItems[1].Text)
                           .Except(LstView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                           .Select(x => x.SubItems[1].Text));

MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} Missing.", string.Join(",", diff), "\n"));
```

Now how do I extract the information out from variable `diff` to a single string? It needs to be separated to different string.

Comment: what kind of out put you are having for the `diff` ? Is it a `list` with `strings` or ?

Comment: its a list that i combine to a string.

Comment: Are you having any exceptions? or any errors?

Comment: Try this one please `MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} Missing.", String.Join(",", diff)));`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you would like to concatenate the items into a comma separated string.

Try this:

```
result = diff.Aggregate(result, (current, item) => current + string.Format("{0},", item));
MessageBox(string.Format("List duplicates: {0}", result.TrimEnd(Convert.ToChar(","));
```

Hope this helps.